# Setting multiple variables from opened file - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I open a file using a python programme.

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

Then I set a variable:

```
data = file.read()
```

And another one:

```
data2 = file.readlines()
```

The data variable should be a string and data2 a list. Printing data works fine, but when I try to print data2, I get an empty list. Why does it work like that? Why does setting data iterfere with data2?

Comment: What's in the file and how do you want it to be stored in your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have consumed the iterator with `file.read()` so there is nothing left to consume when you call `readlines`, you would need to `file.seek(0)` before the call to `readlines` to reset the pointer to the start of the file.

```
with open('test.txt') as f: # with closes your files automatically
    data = f.read() 
    f.seek(0) # reset file pointer
    data2 = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do that, or do I have to close the file and re-open it?

Comment: @ZeroFunter, no worries, I presume this is just some experimentation?

Answer (score 3):

When you open a file it returns a file pointer. This means that you can only read each line once. After you use `read()`, it reads the entire file, moving the file pointer to the end. Then when you use `readlines()` it returns an empty list because there are no lines past the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that setting `data` interferes with `data2`. Rather, it is calling `file.read()` interfering with `file.readlines()`.

When you opened the file with `file = open('test.txt', 'r')`, the variable `file` is now a pointer to the file.

Thus, when you call `file.read()` or `file.readlines()`, it moves the pointer `file`.

`file.read()` moves the pointer to the end of the file, so there is no more like to read for `file.readlines()`.

Even though you are assigning them to different variable, they ultimately depend on `file`. So by setting `data`, you modify `file` which interferes with your attempt to set `data2`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split the string instead of reading the file again.

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
data2 = data.split('\n')
```

Comment: Not the answer I was searching for, as I wanted to know why it worked like that, but that would definitelly work as well.